# emacs, writing custom commands which use term-mode

Tags: emacs

I'm using Emacs and <kbd>M-x</kbd>`term` for a terminal. Since my typical workflow looks like this:

- edit some code
- <kbd>C-x o</kbd> to the terminal buffer (or <kbd>C-x b</kbd>`term[Enter]` or something)
- press <kbd>Up</kbd> key to use the last command
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run it
- <kbd>C-x o</kbd> to go back

I want to bind all of these (except the first step... maybe) to one command, I believe Emacs is awesome enough to do that :-)

So, a command must:

- go to the buffer with terminal (maybe it shouldn't change any windows at all, maybe it should split the window vertially (if it weren't split already) and use the right sid)
- run a last command what've been run there
- go back to the last buffer/part of the screen

Thank you! I'm not really used to the Emacs scripting system, and I hope someone will help me and someone else will be able to use the answer to improve his workflow, since I believe this is a pretty common one

---

Examples of commands:

```
python manage.py test
python manage.py test stats
python solve.py # for project-euler puzzles :-)
```

the first and the second runs over a ssh (in a terminal) sometimes (I like developing with `vagrant`)

I understand that it's easy to bind the first and the third ones, but the second changes too often - I'd just like to "run last command"

Comment: It sounds like you're switching windows to do some sort of code compilation. If so, you should investigate the commands built into the coding modes which do this already w/o a separate shell. Give a concrete example of what you're trying to do and you'll get a better response.

Comment: not actually, I'll add examples

Answer (score 1):

Quick & dirty - define a macro:

```
F3
C-x b term RET
UP RET
C-x b RET
F4
```

Now pressing `F4` again will repeat the actions you've done between the last `F3`/`F4` pair. You can do much more with macros, including having more than one macro, editing macros, saving macros in `.emacs`, etc. For more info look at [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) and [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `M-x compile` allow one to do something similar? It allows you to type a custom command and run it, then repeat this the next time...

Well, probably there will be problems with interactive commands (that's why you would like to use a term), and perhaps also with a persistent reusable ssh-connection (but TRAMP could help here: `cd REMOTELOCATION; your_cmd` could work).

So, at least, you can look at `compile`'s source code to learn how buffers are maanged for such a scenario, and how commands are executed.